# Disable specific errors

Tags: c, gcc

Is it possible to turn off all `macro` and `pasting` errors (or errors of any types)?
ie:

```
error: macro "macro_name" passed 1 arguments, but takes just 0
error: pasting "&" and "0" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

The reason is that I'm debugging code that has a bunch of these errors (which I haven't fixed yet) that are making it harder to see the other types of errors that I'm trying to fix first.

Comment: The best solution is to fix the `errors` first - that's why they're so hard to 'turn off'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's why they're errors instead of warnings; the compiler doesn't know what to do with/how to work around them.  You should usually fix errors in the order they come up anyway, *especially* the preprocessor errors you want to turn off, because an error in one part of the code can propagate and cause "errors" in other, correct, parts of the code.  If you're getting too many errors, use `make 2>&1 | less` to get them without scrolling back.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output of the compiler to a text file, and then read the text file to find your errors. You could remove the "un-interesting" errors via RegEx or something similar.